Alternatives to `docker commit` in this scenario?
I'm trying to build a Docker image (based on debian:latest) for cross compilation. One step within this process is the creation of a cross-compilation sysroot, which involves running the following command within the running container:
mk-sbuild \
  --name=rpi3b-bookworm \
  --arch=arm64 \
  --debootstrap-mirror="http://ftp.debian.org/debian" \
  --skip-proposed --skip-updates --skip-security \
  bookworm

However, this command only works if the container is started with docker run --priviledged (because it needs to chroot and what not). It seems like there's no way to pass this flag to docker build.
What are my options to save the image besides docker commit after running mk-sbuild? I heard that using docker commit is discouraged. Is there any way to run this command inside the Dockerfile?

Can you create the chroot environment on the host system, and COPY it into the image?  That's essentially how the base debian image is created.  For that matter, it might work to create a build stage FROM --platform=... debian, and then COPY that environment into the target image.  In some ways a Docker image is a lot like a glorified chroot that's harder to escape, and so this combination is a little unusual; since you need root-equivalent permissions to run docker commands, just using a host chroot environment may be simpler.

Turns out debootstrap is the more appropriate tool for making a cross-compilation sysroot. The difference is that mk-sbuild will fail if it cannot mount /proc inside the chroot (which is only possible with the --priviledged Docker flag), whereas debootstrap simply issues a warning.
For reference, this is the complete Dockerfile that I ended up with:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/cpp:debian-12

ARG sysroot_path=/home/vscode/rpi3b-bookworm-arm64

# Make apt non-interactive (or else the build might hang)
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        file neovim \
        clangd clang-format \
        debootstrap \
        gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu \
        g++-aarch64-linux-gnu \
        gfortran-aarch64-linux-gnu \
        qemu-user-static

# Use debootstrap to make the sysroot
RUN debootstrap --arch=arm64 --foreign bookworm \
    "$sysroot_path" "http://deb.debian.org/debian"

# Due to the foreign architecture, the 2nd-stage has to be run separately
RUN chroot "$sysroot_path" \
    /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage

# Install more packages
RUN chroot "$sysroot_path" \
    apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libgpiod-dev \
        libfmt-dev libfmt-doc libfmt9

